# My Kubernetes Pods keep crashing with a CrashLoopBackOff error on my worker nodes

Tags: proxy, kubernetes, calico

I'm new to Kubernetes so this may be a dumb problem. Any pods I try to deploy on my worker nodes crash with a CrashLoopBackOff error. This only happens to pods running on my worker nodes and not my leader. Even creating a dummy pod on the worker node fails.

Some of the running pods:

```
$ kubectl get pods -A
NAMESPACE     NAME                                       READY   STATUS             RESTARTS        AGE
default       test-pod                                   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   6 (3m44s ago)   178m
kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-866dcccff9-6s8vb   1/1     Running            0               40m
kube-system   calico-node-bq4xm                          0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   9 (4m34s ago)   37m
kube-system   calico-node-w7qb5                          0/1     Running            0               51m
kube-system   kube-proxy-hwwrs                           0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   9 (98s ago)     35m
kube-system   kube-proxy-vwrwx                           1/1     Running            0               3d6h
```

`test-pod`, `calico-node-bq4xm`, `kube-proxy-hwwrs` are pods running on the worker node. I deleted some of the pods to force recreation in hopes that would fix it.

Events from describing the worker node:

```
Events:
  Type    Reason    Age    From        Message
  ----    ------    ----   ----        -------
  Normal  Starting  56m    kube-proxy
  Normal  Starting  54m    kube-proxy
  Normal  Starting  54m    kube-proxy
  Normal  Starting  52m    kube-proxy
  Normal  Starting  50m    kube-proxy
  Normal  Starting  48m    kube-proxy
  Normal  Starting  44m    kube-proxy
  Normal  Starting  38m    kube-proxy
  Normal  Starting  30m    kube-proxy
  Normal  Starting  24m    kube-proxy
  Normal  Starting  18m    kube-proxy
  Normal  Starting  11m    kube-proxy
  Normal  Starting  4m55s  kube-proxy
```

Describing the kube-proxy-hwwrs pod:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason          Age                    From               Message
  ----     ------          ----                   ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled       59m                    default-scheduler  Successfully assigned kube-system/kube-proxy-hwwrs to james-k8s
  Normal   Created         54m (x4 over 59m)      kubelet            Created container kube-proxy
  Normal   Started         54m (x4 over 59m)      kubelet            Started container kube-proxy
  Normal   SandboxChanged  53m (x4 over 56m)      kubelet            Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Normal   Pulled          14m (x12 over 59m)     kubelet            Container image "registry.k8s.io/kube-proxy:v1.28.4" already present on machine
  Warning  BackOff         9m18s (x175 over 56m)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container kube-proxy in pod kube-proxy-hwwrs_kube-system(3cd07dd8-8b2d-4535-a656-8910346c638d)
  Normal   Killing         3m31s (x13 over 57m)   kubelet            Stopping container kube-proxy
```

I checked the available disk space and memory and everything looks good. I've tried deleting the pod so it will be recreated but still the same. Funny enough if I change the label to force it to run on the leader, it works, which makes me think something is wrong on the workers.

Is there anything else I should check to find out what is causing the error? What is different about my worker node vs leader node?

Comment: Please share logs from one of those pods (e.g. the "kube-proxy-hwwrs" one; logs can be accessed via "kubectl logs"). It would also be helpful to know what tool/distribution you used to set up Kubernetes.